# What is FlutterFlow LImitiation? is it good to work with it for a 4 years experience developer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I am a flutter developer with 4 years of experience, and I was thinking about **FlutterFlow** platform.

Will it facilitate the development process for relatively small and medium Projects? I want to get feedback from experienced developers who have already tried it on their projects, can I build a custom design or complex animation with it? Or can I easily modify it after downloading the source code?

**Note:** My main purpose of using it is to reduce development time, not to help me with coding.